# JS: Build sum of values from multiple id's

Tags: javascript, function, range, document-ready

I have this HTML + JS:

```
<input type="text" id="first" value="" />
<input type="text" id="second" value="" />
<input type="text" id="third" value="" />

<b id="result"></b>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $range = $("#first"), $result = $("#result");

 var track = function () {
  var $this = $(this), value = $this.prop("value");
  $result.html("Value: " + value);
 };

 $range.on("change", track);
});
</script>
```

This gets the instant value of a range slider with the id "first" and outputs it immediately within the element "result". Works fine.

But now I want to output one sum of all id's "first", "second", "third" and so on.

How can I do this within this code?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML for `#first`, `#result`... etc?

Comment: The item with the ID `first` is missing to be exact

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and expected results

Comment: I edited my post. The values are assigned via JS, so the values in the inputs are empty within HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you may find it easier to assign a CSS class to all of the range fields you'd like to sum the values for. This will then allow you to find them all within the DOM using a single selector.

But all you need to do is find all of the range elements, loop through them, summing their values as you go. Then assign the result to your div.

```js
$(function () {
    var $range = $('#first, #second, #third');
    var $result = $('#result');

    function track(event) {
        var total = 0;

        $range.each(function (i, element) {
            total += parseInt($(element).val(), 10);
        });

        $result.html('Value: ' + total);
    }

    $range.on('change', track);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="first" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="1">
<input id="second" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="2">
<input id="third" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="3">

<div id="result"></div>
```

I've assumed you're using integer values. If not, you will need to remove the integer casting with `parseInt`.

Comment: I used parseFloat because the values have commas.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event listener three times, using `.on()`, as you have done for just the first one. Then instead of doing `$this.prop` you will want to actually grab each individual one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var $first = $("#first"), $second = $("#second"), $third = $("#third"), $result = $("#result");

 var track = function () {
  var value = $first.prop("value") + $second.prop("value") + $third.prop("value");
  $result.html("Value: " + value);
 };

 $first.on("change", track);
 $second.on("change", track);
 $third.on("change", track);
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my question. I want to have ONE sum of all the id's NOT multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Select all the elements and use `.reduce()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const result = $("#result");

  const range = $("#first,#second,#third")
      .on("change", function() {
         result.html("Value: " + 
            range.toArray().reduce((sum, el) => sum + +el.value, 0));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" value="1" />
<input type="text" id="second" value="2" />
<input type="text" id="third" value="3" />

<b id="result"></b>
```

Assigning a common class would be nicer than selecting by ID, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `$.fn.extend()`:

```js
// external.js
$(function(){
$.fn.extend({
  valSum: function(){
    var c = 0;
    this.each(function(){
      c += +$(this).val();
    });
    return c;
  }
});
$('#frm').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
// I would give them all a class instead - but
var sum = $('.sum');
sum.change(function(){
  $('#output').html(sum.valSum());
});
});
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>.valSum()</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='main'>
      <form id='frm' name='frm'>
        <label for='first'>First</label>
        <input id='first' name='first' class='sum' type='text' />
        <label for='second'>Second</label>
        <input id='second' name='second' class='sum' type='text' />
        <label for='third'>Third</label>
        <input id='third' name='third' class='sum' type='text' />
      </form>
      <div id='output'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`.valSum()` should work on any selector now, with inputs anyways. So,

```
var fst = $('#first, #second, #third');
fst.change(function(){
  $('#output').html(fst.valSum());
});
```

should also work without adding the HTML class.

Since this is more reusable, it should be how you code.

Comment: Sorry about the edits. Took me a while to fully test.